# Airflow DAG analysis of changing daily job to hourly job and impact on his dependencies

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

we have  3 DAG's (Dag-a,Dag-b,Dag-c) that's  going to be hourly job instead of Daily job which are scheduled at @daily 8 AM  .  Also there is one daily job(Dag-x)  which has dependency on this 3 DAG's marked in External Task sensor  runs @daily at 9 am  . Before changing the schedule interval to  60 minutes, i would like to know that daily job (Dag-x)
should not get triggered when the hourly triggers happens. How to ensure and test it well on this changing of schedule interval .Also how to do impact analysis of any Dag within  apache airflow  on the dependencies , any tool to achieve it ? .

Please advise.

Comment: Hi Team, please help me out on this.